# Can I ask how/where an existing game uses a particular feature of a graphics API?

Tags: discussion

Let's say there is an existing game and it's common knowledge that it uses a particular feature of a mainstream graphics API (OpenGL, specifically). While I'm a programmer, I'm not much of a game developer type, so it's not completely clear to me where exactly that game puts that feature to use. However, out of technical curiosity, I would like to get a general description, if that's possible.

Can I ask such a question here, or would it be off-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't ask how a specific game implements a specific feature with a specific API, as the only valid answer would be from a programmer of the game; all others would be pure speculations.

You can, however, ask how you *could* implement the specific feature of the specific game with a specific API. Adding a link to a youtube video (bookmarked at a relevant time) or a screenshot would help a lot.

This type of question is more open ended, removes any speculation and welcome more answers!

Comment: I see. Just to be clear: I don't want to know how they implemented Game Feature X. I want to know what use they found for API Feature Y. (In a way, it's the reverse question.)

Comment: That's still a question only the developers of game X can answer.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Not necessarily, although it might be the case -- at least for the one I have in mind. Asking the developers was my first thought, but I thought that maybe asking it as question here might add some value to the site for future readers (if it was on-topic, of course).

Comment: If your question is "How was [insert OpenGL feature] benecifial for the development process of [insert game name here]?" there's no way someone who is not the developer of [insert game name here] can answer that question *correctly*.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Tyyppi_77 sums it up.